# How to isolate $n$ in the inequality $ 3n + 7n^3\gt c(17 + 34n^2) $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have an equation 
$$ 3n + 7n^3\gt c\left(17 + 34n^2\right)
$$
and I want to turn this inequality into something like 
$$ n \gt c(\mbox{something that does not have}\ n)
$$
I don't know why but always get stumped at these types of questions. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Without much thinking: If $n$ was a positive number, in this specific case you could use the $AM\geq GM$ inequality on the right side. $$3n+7n^3>c(17+34n^2)\geq c\cdot 2\cdot(\sqrt{17\cdot 34}n) $$. Since we assume a positive number the rest is easy to get a result, it may just not be very strong.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is equivalent to finding the minimum of
$$\frac{n(7n^2+3)}{34n^2+17}=\frac{n}{34}\left(7-\frac1{2n^2+1}\right)$$
Which for positive numbers, is clearly increasing. So you need to find only the least $n$ satisfying the cubic.

Checking for $n$ near $\frac{34}7c$ may quickly solve it, depending on the value of $c$.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do involves solving a cubic equation. It is possible but the solution is a so complicated formula that it is rather useless in most cases; the parameter $c$ makes things even tougher.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it as

$$
n(7n^2+34cn+3)>17c
$$

Hopefully, the 2nd degree term at the left hand side can be put as $(n+\alpha)(n+\beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will probably depend on $c$